# Undownloadable dependencies

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm working on a package that has a proprietary dependency with no public download location. If `pip` finds that this specific dependency isn't installed, I want to either abort the install, or print a warning and continue with the dependency uninstalled. I want to configure this on my end, probably in `setup.py`, not as something users have to specify when installing my package.

I specifically want pip to not even *try* to download or install the dependency from anywhere; particularly, if pip tries to download the dependency from PyPI, someone could register something bad with the dependency's name and pip would install that.

There are ways to specify [*alternate* download links](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi) for a dependency that should be downloaded from somewhere other than PyPI, but I haven't found a way to say that a dependency shouldn't be downloaded at all.

The best workaround I've found is to simply not put the dependency on the `install_requires` list at all, but then there's no indication that the dependency exists and no warning if you install the package without the dependency.

Is there a way to say that a specific dependency should not be downloaded?

Answer (score 3):

> If pip finds that this specific dependency isn't installed, I want to either abort the install...

If I understand you correctly, you could check if the proprietary package is installed by simply trying to import a module from that package in your `setup.py`, aborting on `ImportError`. As an example, let's say your dependency that should abort the installation is `numpy`:

```
from distutils.command.build import build as build_orig
from distutils.errors import DistutilsModuleError
from setuptools import setup


class build(build_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        try:
            import numpy
        except ImportError:
            raise DistutilsModuleError('numpy is not installed. Installation will be aborted.')
        super().finalize_options()


setup(
    name='spam',
    version='0.1',
    author='nobody',
    author_email='nobody@nowhere.com',
    packages=[],
    install_requires=[
        # all the other dependencies except numpy go here as usual
    ],
    cmdclass={'build': build,},
)
```

Now, you should distribute your package as source tar because wheels won't invoke `setup.py` on installation:

```
$ python setup.py sdist
```

Trying to install the built tar when `numpy` is missing will result in:

```
$ pip install dist/spam-0.1.tar.gz 
Processing ./dist/spam-0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/spam.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/spam.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/spam.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/spam.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/spam.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/spam.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

    error: numpy is not installed. Installation will be aborted.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_y/2qk6029j4c7bwv0ddk3p96r00000gn/T/pip-s8sqn20t-build/
```

Note that I could do the import check on top of the setup script:

```
from setuptools import setup

try:
    import numpy
except ImportError:
    raise DistutilsModuleError(...)

setup(...)
```

But in this case, the output won't be formatted and the complete stack trace will be spilled to the stdout, which is too technical and could confuse the user. Instead, I subclass one of the `distutils` commands that will be invoked on installation, so that the error output is properly formatted.

Now, for the second part:

> ...or print a warning and continue with the dependency uninstalled.

This is not possible anymore, since version 7 [pip will swallow any output from your setup script](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2933). The user will see the output from the setup script only if pip runs in verbose mode, i.e. `pip install -v mypkg`. A questionable decision if you ask me.

Nevertheless, here is an example of issuing a warning and an error in your setup script:

```
from distutils.log import ERROR

class build(build_orig):

    def finalize_options(self):
        try:
            import numpy
        except ImportError:
            # issue an error and proceed
            self.announce('Houston, we have an error!', level=ERROR)
            # for warnings, there is a shortcut method
            self.warn('I am warning you!')
        super().finalize_options()
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for `cmdclass`? I can't find it.

Comment: @user2357112 it's part of Python's stdlib. [Extending Distutils](https://docs.python.org/3.6/distutils/extending.html) should be a good starting point.